# Mercurial pull from bitbucket times out. Artist commited too large of a file then deleted it in a later commit

Tags: macos, mercurial, timeout

Currently I am unable to pull from my repository on bitbucket as it times out after 15 minutes or so. I am using SourceTree on mac as my program. I have tried pulling many times but it keeps failing and rolling back. Is there a way to do a partial pull or some other workaround? I'm not sure where to type in commands like `hg pull` from SourceTree.

I tried copying the large files from the artist's computer to mine but the pull continues to time out.

Any help would be much appreciated as I don't want to clone the whole repository and lose my changes I've made locally in the last couple of days.

The error log is as follows:

```
transaction abort!
rollback completed
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: wightwhale
pulling from https://wightwhale@bitbucket.org/wightwhale/this-is-not-a-ball-game
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
abort: connection ended unexpectedly
Completed with errors, see above
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If pulling directly fails, but you are able to do a new clone, there's no need to throw away your local changes (or even you current main clone): just make a new clone to a separate local directory, and pull from it locally (entering that separate local directory as the pull source on your main local repository).

In the command line, that could be:

```
hg clone https://wightwhale@bitbucket.org/wightwhale/this-is-not-a-ball-game /tmp/temporaryclone
cd /my/main/local/repository
hg pull /tmp/temporaryclone
```

Another option could be stripping the offending changeset from Bitbucket. But in this case all developers need to strip the same revisions from their local repositories; see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory for details.